# typo3, tt_news: multiple single view pages

Tags: typo3

I have a site that has news and press releases. Both using tt_news.
I want these pages to have different single views.

As it is now the news posts on the press release page links to the news page single view.

**Press page url:**
http://ucms-russia.gluteus.se/about-us/press-about-us/

**Press page link url:**
http://ucms-russia.gluteus.se/news/news-post/668/

**News page url:**
http://ucms-russia.gluteus.se/news/

I want the press page link url to look like this:
http://ucms-russia.gluteus.se/about-us/press-about-us/press-post/668/

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a solution.

I added this into a template setup for the page that listed the press posts

```
plugin.tt_news {
    # page with single view
        singlePid = 518
    # page with list view
        backPid = 517
}
```